# How to find out if Unity plugin hangs (from unityscript)

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

Unity player on my page hangs sometimes. Is it possible to detect it from unityscript (polling method is acceptable) and react to that- for example reload page?

Answer (score 2):

a colleague ran into this issue, I believe that after an extend research with no good results he came up with this solution:

- In the web page declare a global variable `stillAlive` for example.
- Use `setInterval` to check for that variable every `n` second, something like this:

  `if (stillAlive){
      stillAlive = false;
  }else{
  //do things
  }`
- Make an [`Application.ExternalEval`](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Application.ExternalEval.html) call in your application every `n/2` seconds, something like this

  `Application.ExternalEval ("stillAlive=true;");`

I don't know the exact details, but he did something to sync those. I'm sure you can figure something out along this idea.

Note: For some reason I couldn't format the code in this answer, so if someone can fix it, please do.

**Update:** I've just asked him, he said he "synced" them by initiating the `setInterval()` with `Application.ExternalEval()`.